# How to I assign the ttf font file in the vfs_fonts.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fonts, pdfkit, pdfmake

I am trying to add the custom fonts into vfs_fonts.js but I didn't understand what needs to be written in the value field of window.pdfMake object?

I have my key as "MyFont.ttf" and I know that value is nothing but ttf file. My ttf is a physical file not a set of characters. How do I fill the value field?

```
 window.pdfMake = window.pdfMake || {}; window.pdfMake.vfs = {
      "Roboto-Italic.ttf": "AAEAAAASAQAABA",
      "Roboto-Medium.ttf": "AAEAAA",
      "MyFont.ttf":"???????????????????"
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: can someone answer this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/*  Read the documenation at https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake 
specially the readme file */

<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <title>my first pdfmake example</title>
   <script src='build/pdfmake.min.js'></script>
   <script src='build/vfs_fonts.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>


// works great with the default vfs_fonts.js

   pdfMake.fonts = {
      Roboto: {
         normal: 'Roboto-Regular.ttf',
         bold: 'Roboto-Medium.ttf',
         italics: 'Roboto-Italic.ttf',
         bolditalics: 'Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf'
      }
   };

 // open the PDF in a new window
   pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();


</script>

</body>
```

Comment: FYI: don't write, copy, paste the font into the vfs_fonts.js file.

Comment: use gulp buildFonts to create your vfs_fonts.js file from the ttf font files